# MongoDB Time Series for a Process Historian : query by different bytes of the _id field

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I want to store timeseries data in a mongodb. I know, i know, there are many articles about this in the net, but not a single one offered the solution to exactly my problem, and many of them refer to the old mmap storage engine, and I use WiredTiger, and many of them deal with equidistant timeseries. The aim is to achieve the best compromise between read and write throughput while ensuring maximum scalability (even to terabytes of time series data) and minimum disk storage size / ram consumption. This also means a minimum amount of indexes. The historian needs to have the ability to import past data, which is why new data is not always added with increasing timestamp. Ive already developed a minimalistic schema:

```
{
    "_id": "f061e95ae4dc281aea4df2f8",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Time": "2018-05-02T07:56:40.545Z",
            "Value": "529"
        },
        {
            "Time": "2018-05-02T07:56:51.119Z",
            "Value": "254"
        },
...
    ]
}
```

This document represents one chunk of data which belongs to one signal and one one hour in time (the data will feature smallest but non-equidistant sampling times of about 1 second). The collection only contains documents like this one and only has one index (on _id of course). The _id of the document is generated based on the hash of the unique identifier of this signal and the beginning of the utc hour to which the bucket of data belongs.

As you see, for querying the data, I compute a set of ids based on the given timerange and the signal identifier. The first 4 bytes of the _id encode the utc hour, the last 8 bytes the hash of the signal identifier. Therefore, a query asking for one day of data of one signal will result in a query trying to retrieve 24 ids. The problem is: for large time ranges (e.g. starting from epoch until now), I have to query a lot of IDs (e.g. 400000) which seems to make the query quite slow. The (shortened) mongodb db query (in C#):

```
FilterDefinition<DBTimeSeries> f = Builders<DBTimeSeries>.Filter.Empty;
var filterbuilder = Builders<DBTimeSeries>.Filter;
IEnumerable ids = Helpers.GetIDs(start, end, tagname);
var f = Builders<DBTimeSeries>.Filter.Empty;
f = f & filterbuilder.In(x => x.ID, ids);
var chunks = await collection.FindAsync<DBTimeSeries>(f);
```

Even with a small amount of data in the database, this query takes up to one minute to execute. The ID property is of type "ObjectId" from the mongodb C# driver.

I know that this is possible

```
f = f & filterbuilder.Where(x => x.ID > new ObjectId(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), 0, 0, 0) && x.ID < new ObjectId(DateTime.Now, 0, 0, 0))
```

which means I can do time range querys on IDs, but this does not give me the ability to query the data for one specific signal without adding an additional field to the document presented above. I'd even have to index this field for better performance.

Therefore my question: It would be optimal to be able to query the _id by a query like: "Give me the documents whose first 4 bytes of the _id field represent a uint32 between x and y and whose last 8 bytes of the _id field are equal to a given unit64". The query should use indexes exclusively, which should be possible since all the information is stored within the _id field. I know about the $bitsAllSet option (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAllSet/#op._S_bitsAllSet), but i can somehow only pass a long in the C# driver and queries seem not to be able to use an index for the $bitsAllSet part of the query...

Does anybody have an idea? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to restructure your data? Using the _id field to store both the signal identifier and the bucket timestamp makes it difficult to index the two of them. Could you not store the signal identifier as one field and the bucket timestamp as a separate date field, allowing you to index them as normal?

Comment: Thank you for you help, Vince! Yes of course, adding an indexed signal identifier field to the bucket document would be an easy solution, but in theory all I need is availible in the _id field this way. It would be great if the problem could be solved using only one index, if I can even do a time range query on the _id (which in the end is a query on the first 4 bytes of the _id), it should also be possible to include in the query the much less complex "match the last 8 bytes of the _id with a pattern I provide you" statement.

Comment: OK, makes sense. I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your question, to try and capture the crucial part of what you're trying to do. Remember, you're encouraged to [edit] and re-edit questions as necessary, to improve them as much as possible.

Comment: @heapoverflow few questions 1) Could you post the [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) output ? 2) why is your `_id` value in string format ? 3) Would your `_id` value be sequential ? I'd assume so, but just to confirm. Thanks.